# Object Foreign Property Is Not Populating

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm new to EF so sorry if the question is ... you know.

I have two entities objects; User and UserRole

In the user object I have a property UserRole and another one UserRoleId but the property UserRole is null.

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int UserRoleId { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    public UserRole UserRole { get; set; }
}

public class UserRole
{
    public int UserRoleId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }

    public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

I want the property UserRole populated.

Comment: u need to specify relationship between User and UserRole, this most likely should be write in DBContext.OnModelCreating function.

Comment: You are question is not clear! Are you saying that when you querying `User` then `UserRole` is null? Is it?

Comment: Take a look at [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) section of the documentation.

Comment: @TanvirArjel Yes, is it

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I just need to enable the lazy loading proxy

```
  optionsBuilder
            .UseLazyLoadingProxies()
            .UseSqlServer(connString);
```